# Массив в строку

Tags: java, массивы

Доброго времени суток. Есть массив чисел.

Подскажите, как правильно сделать массив, для последующего вывода в `System.out.println` чисел в одну строку без пробелов и разделителей. И не знаю как правильно сделать, чтобы массив состоял из количества элементов, равному количеству выводимых символов (в коде у меня задан 20, но это естессно неправильно).

Comment: а что этот код вообще делает? Может напишите задачу, этот код конечно можно поправить но мне кажется переписать лучше. Вы считаете что это самый нормальный способ десятичное в двоичное преобразовать?

Comment: @pavel, задача состояла перевести, без использования Integer.toBinaryString (), вот и своими методами наваял) Да и дело не способе, а в выводе итога

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы как-то так сделал.

```
class toBin{
    ArrayList<Integer> arr;

    toBin(int number) { 
        arr = new ArrayList<>();
        for ( ; number > 0; number/=2)
              arr.add(number & 1);
        for (int x : arr)
           System.out.print(x);
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько способов:

1. Guava Joiners: http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html
2. или так в java8

   ```
   Optional<String> str = Arrays.stream(a)
       .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
       .reduce((e, t) -> t.concat(e))
       .map(e -> new StringBuilder(e).reverse().toString());

   if (str.isPresent()) System.out.println(str.get());
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно сделать вывод массива чисел в виде строки для `System.out.println()` без пробелов и знаков разделителей:

```
    public class PrintIntArray{
             public static String arrayIntToString(int[] arr){
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int element: arr)
                           sb.append(element);
                    return String.valueOf(sb);
             }

             public static void main(String[] args) {
                    int[] i = {1,2,3};
                    System.out.println(arrayIntToString(i));
             }

     } /* Output:
       123   
     *///:~
```